# How to use this command line in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, windows, batch

I ask my question in the form of an example ... I have a folder containing several subfolders that are as follows
Main folder==)Got, Vikings, etc.
In each one there is videos with their corresponding srt files. In the windows environment, running this command in the main folder make mkvmerge to mux whole videos and corresponding srt files in this directory.

```
For /R %%A IN (*.mkv *.mp4) Do (
    "C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~dpnxAtemp" "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.srt" && if errorlevel 2 (
        echo errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
    ) else if errorlevel 1 (
        del /f "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.srt" echo Warnings generated during remuxing to "%%~A", original file deleted
    ) else (
        del /f "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.srt" echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~A", original file deleted
    ) && for /R %%A IN (*.mkvtemp *.mp4temp) do ren "%%~fA" "%**.mkv"
)
Pause
```

Comment: Is the `if errorlevel 2` part ever called? It’s preceded by `&&`, so it would be only run if ERRORLEVEL equals 0, wouldn’t it?

Comment: I don’t question setting ERRORLEVEL by `mkvmerge` but is the error message from your script printed then? As I wrote in my previous comment, I doubt it would run the part after `&&` if `mkvmerge` returns an ERRORLEVEL > 0. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html I think the script should be fixed before converting it.

Comment: I think your code in the body of `if errorlevel 2`, i.e. the error message, will never be executed. The part after `&&` is only executed if ERRORLEVEL equals 0 but the code requires ERROLEVEL equal 2 and this never happens together. Also do the other `echo`’s work? In your one-line code, they simply come after `del`, so they would be likely interpreted as further arguments to `del`…

Comment: I understand and agree with that but I think your code does not work as intended in such a situation.

Comment: Video is an overkill. I just wanted an answer to my question whether your error messages get printed in reality.

Comment: Printed = echoed = shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code contains some errors but I understand it in the following way:<sup>1</sup>

> Run the following on all `*.mkv` and `*.mp4` found recursively:
>
> 1. Run `mkvmerge` on each file and its corresponding `*.srt`.
> 2. If it succeeded (warning or clean exit):
>
>    - Delete the input files.
>    - Rename the created file to `<original_name>.mkv`.

This could be done using the following script on Ubuntu.
**Use it at your own risk, I haven’t fully tested it!**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find . -name \*.mp4 -o -name \*.mkv | while read orig_filename
do
   filename="${orig_filename::-4}"  # crop the extension
   mkvmerge -o "$orig_filename.tmp" "$orig_filename" "$filename.srt"
   if [ $? -le 1 ]  # warning or clean exit
   then
       rm "$orig_filename" "$filename.srt"
       mv "$orig_filename.tmp" "$filename.mkv"
   fi
done
```

Before running this script, you need to install the [`mkvmerge`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=mkvmerge) program for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install mkvtoolnix
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I have left out error messages for simplicity. As per comments, they don’t seem to be essential for the script.

Comment: Be sure ... since I have not yet tried, I did not approve your answer. As soon as I've tried the code, I'll let you know.